# Add-in support broken starting with Mac Outlook update 16.13.1

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

Has anyone noticed that with the 16.13.1 Mac Outlook update the addin buttons in the ribbon and even the 'Store' button itself started disappearing?

Our add-in users that use hosted Exchange accounts (i.e. AppRiver or Rackspace) started reporting these issues recently and in one case also our addin is having trouble starting, getting null for Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress.

Has the Outlook update introduced bugs?

More problems with this and the next version 16.14.1:

For hosted mailboxes (i.e. @Rackspace) Office.js API returns 'undefined' for Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress and Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName

and returns Item.internetMessageId returns an incorrect message-id because '<>' are stripped!

Comment: Thanks for raising it. Could you please provide exact build number? Is it happening for all users of the tenant or only few users seeing it?

Comment: My version is 16.13.1 (180523) and experience the issue with the buttons. Sometimes they disappear than if you wait long enough they may come back. Another user I know installed an Insider version yesterday hoping the issue is resolved there. I'll find out the exact version. We're experiencing Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress=null with just one user, trying to debug further if the issue is somehow in our code.

Comment: Our partner also reports: "We are even seeing it in Outlook.com/Live.com email addresses too. Is there a way to revert back to older builds in Mac or a way to uninstall and load an older one"?

Comment: the issue has been fixed and will be available in the next insider fast release.

Comment: Thank you. We'll try to confirm with our users.

Comment: When will the fix be available as a stable release? We have a reproducible case here where Office.js API returns 'undefined' for Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress and Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName